# Hooking IE Events in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com

I am trying to capture events from an existing IE window. In the code sample below, I am attempting to capture the `mouseClick` event within the browser document when a user clicks on an element, and then eventually pull back some attributes about the element being clicked.

```
public partial class frmBrowserElementBuilder : Form
{
    InternetExplorer ie;
    public frmBrowserElementBuilder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmBrowserElementBuilder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create IE
        ie = new InternetExplorer();
        ie.Visible = true;

        //handle document completed
        ie.DocumentComplete += new
      DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(DocumentComplete);

    }

    public void DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        //document was loaded
        //MessageBox.Show("DocumentComplete: " + URL);

        //create event handler and hook onclick from IE
        DHTMLEventHandler onClickHandler = new DHTMLEventHandler(ie.Document);
        onClickHandler.assignedEvent += new DHTMLEvent(this.ie_onClick);
        ie.Document.onclick = onClickHandler;
    }

    private void ie_onClick(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
    {
        //something was clicked
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Event Hooked {0}, Qualifier {1}", e.type, e.qualifier));
    }

    public delegate void DHTMLEvent(IHTMLEventObj e);

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class DHTMLEventHandler
    {
        public DHTMLEvent assignedEvent;

        private mshtml.HTMLDocument document;
        public DHTMLEventHandler(mshtml.HTMLDocument doc)
        {
            //assign to instance of IE document
            this.document = doc;
        }

        [DispId(0)]
        public void Call()
        {
            //call the event
            assignedEvent(this.document.parentWindow.@event); //{System.InvalidCastException: "Specified cast is not valid."}
        }

    }

}
```

The code compiles and the void Call() triggers as expected, however, the value of `this.document.parentwindow` is `null` and is throws `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when stepping into the assignedEvent method.`

When I inspect `this.document`, the value of `parentWindow` states

> The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

after forcing evaluation it states:

> '((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)this.document).parentWindow' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [threading](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ac4ae328-a700-4404-8c8f-e72fb22753ce/exception-occurs-when-ihtmlwindow2-window-thedocparentwindow?forum=ieextensiondevelopment) issue. The Call() call happens on an MTA thread, and you can't access MSHTML from an MTA thread. There are many ways to change this, however, the most simple is to do this:

```
public void DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    var events = (HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)ie.Document;
    events.onclick += (evt) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Event Hooked {0}, Qualifier {1}", evt.type, evt.qualifier));
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!